# Why SAS and R give different ARIMA outputs?

Tags: r, sas

I build ARIMA model with regressors in SAS and R, but the model's results are totally different, I cannot figure out why two packages give different outputs.

The following is the SAS code

```
proc ARIMA data=TSDATA;
identify var=LOG_Sale
crosscorr=(
Log_Var1
Log_Var2
Log_Var3)
nlag=12 ALPHA=0.05  WHITENOISE = IGNOREMISS SCAN;
run;
estimate q=(4)(10)
input=
( Log_Var1
Log_Var2
Log_Var3)
method=ml plot ;
run;
```

The following is the R code:

```
finalmodel <- arima (LOG_Sale, order=c(0, 0, 4), seasonal=list  (order=c(0, 0, 1),period=10),include.mean = TRUE, xreg=xinput,fixed=c(0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA),
                     method="ML")
summary(finalmodel)
```

As you can see, the model include MA(4)(10) and 3 regressors, I defined a matrix xinput to include the three regressors(Log_Var1,Log_Var2,Log_Var3).

The coefficients are totally different in two outputs(SAS and R), I don't know why, please help me out if you can point out what's wrong in the R code, because I think the SAS code is quite typical and should be right, but I am new to R and I guess the R code maybe wrong....

Thanks.

Comment: 1) create and use a small data set in sas, 2) run the code and 3) paste the results. 4) use the same data set in r, 5) run the code and 6) paste the results. 7) paste the data set in your question

Answer (score 0):

the data is typical weekly time series data
Date         Log_Var1    Log_Var2    Log_Var3
3-Jan-11    13.47487027 8.65886635  9.096499556
10-Jan-11   14.1688108  9.182043773 9.096499556
17-Jan-11   14.3192497  9.175024027 9.096499556
24-Jan-11   14.54051181 9.1902397   9.096499556
31-Jan-11   14.33370089 9.1902397   9.096499556
7-Feb-11    13.76581591 9.431962767 9.326321786
14-Feb-11   14.09526221 9.29844282  9.326321786
21-Feb-11   14.61994905 9.29844282  9.326321786
28-Feb-11   14.94652204 8.700680735 9.326321786
7-Mar-11    14.71066636 9.026056892 9.348993004

As you can see from SAS code, the model is ARIMA(0,0,4)(0,0,10) with three input series, it's straigtforward in SAS, but I read many R materials and I cannot find any useful documents and examples to show how to build ARIMA with specific high order of p,q or P,Q (subset ARIMA) with external regressors.
the R code you see here actually works in R and the output looks alright, but the coefficients are different from the output in SAS, so I guess the algorithms of ARIMA in R could be different from SAS, but both are using ML method...

so the point is whether the R code is correct or not if the model is ARIMA(0,0,4)(0,0,10), it should be noted that q=(4)(10), which is only 4 and 10, not from 1 to 4 and not from 1 to 10, which is only subset orders.
thanks.